# PEC-backed dielectric material

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, dielectric

For the paper named "[Antenna Miniaturization and Bandwidth Enhancement Using a Reactive Impedance Substrate](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~saraband/KSIEEE/01331627.pdf)" the statement "PEC-backed dielectric material", so what is the meaning of this statement? Is it a normal substrate?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the abstract, the authors seem to use the acronyms PEC and PMC to mean "perfect electric conductor" and "perfect magnetic conductor", respectively.

Comment: Yes I nderstand the two terms , but I cann't understand the meaning of the "backed" dielectric substrate

Comment: The dielectric substrate has a PEC layer on one side (probably copper or silver) and the periodic square patches on the other side.